# what does "the sense in which" means in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

[image: The moral foundation of politics by Ian Shapiro]

Can someone please explain the highlighted sentence in image to me? What does **the sen in which** means? If we reformulate the sentence it becomes **parties are as attentive ... in this sense**.
I explored the meanings of **sense** but I can not decide if it is: **way, aspect, ability of what?**.
Can someone write highlighted sentence more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A: the way or manner [in which] (political) parties are attentive to voters
- B: the way or manner [in which] firms in competitive markets are attentive to consumers.

The first thing to do in a complex comparative situation is to sort out the **two things being compared**, as I just did above.

Now, the word sense. Sense here means **the way** or **how** or the manner.

Political parties are not ***as*** attentive to voters **as** firms in competitive markets are to consumers. [just to see the comparison]
Or:
The way political parties are attentive to voters compared to the way firms in competitive markets are attentive to consumers is attenuated.